# Nomenclature of halogenoalkanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

> Why is the following compound called "**1,1,1-trifluoro-2-chloro-2-bromoethane**"?

[image: 1,1,1-trifluoro-2-chloro-2-bromoethane]

Why is this not called "**1-bromo-1-chloro-2,2,2,trifluoroethane**" alphabetically? (the name, 1,1,1-trifluoro-2-chloro-2-bromoethane was in my *CGP A level* chemistry textbook :))

Comment: Both proposed names, "1,1,1-trifluoro-2-chloro-2-bromoethane" and "1-bromo-1-chloro-2,2,2-trifluoroethane", are not in accordance with IUPAC nomenclature.

Comment: Indeed; neither name is correct.

Comment: thank you!! So the first name from CGP just needs to be written alphabetically as 2-bromo-2-chloro-1,1,1-trifluoroethane and then it would be correct. Please could you explain the rule about the [1,1,1 vs 2,2,2] numbers and why I couldn't write "1-bromo-1-chloro-2,2,2-trifluoroethane"? thanks :D

Comment: It's something called the *'lowest locant set'*, i.e. (1, 1, 1, 2, 2) is considered *lower* than (1, 1, 2, 2, 2): "The lowest set of locants is defined as the set that, when compared term by term with other locant sets, each cited in order of increasing value, has the lowest term at the first point of difference." If you search Stack Exchange for that phrase, or for *"P-14.3.5"*, you'll find more explanations.